# Creating a Data Grid using EASYUI with Json where data type Boolean

Tags: c#, javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-easyui

How can I show both of my boolean field at a time in Data Grid ? 
Example: I wanna show **"True"** and **"False"** in the 1st and 2nd row of the Grid? but Grid will be loaded by JSON.

```
<table id="tblDirection"> 
   <thead> 
     <tr> 
        <th field="ck" checkbox="true"></th> 
        <th field="name" width="120">Direction</th> 
      </tr> 
    </thead> 
</table>
```

Here is javascript code:

```
function RefreshDirection() { 
     $('#tblDirection').empty(); 
     data = [{ id: 0, name: 'Uni Directional' 
}, { id: 1, name: 'Bi Directional'}]; 
data = { "total": "" + data.length + "", "rows": data }; 
$('#tblDirection').datagrid('loadData', data); }
```

but I wanna make this dynamically.

Comment: post your code that you are using.

Comment: <table id="tblDirection">
 <thead> 
  <tr>
<th field="ck" checkbox="true"></th>
<th field="name" width="120">Direction</th>
 </tr> 
</thead>                                         
</table>

function RefreshDirection() {
        $('#tblDirection').empty();
data = [{ id: 0, name: 'Uni Directional' }, { id: 1, name: 'Bi Directional'}];
data = { "total": "" + data.length + "", "rows": data };
$('#tblDirection').datagrid('loadData', data);
}

but I wanna make this dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use formatter for the checkbox field instead of using type=checkbox as follows,

```
//column defintion in html tags
<th field="checkfieldId" width="80" formatter="formatCheckbox" >


//formatter function
function formatCheckbox(value,row,index)
{
 if(value)
    return "<input type='checkbox' checked=true onChange=checkChecked("+index+",this);>";
 else
    return "<input type='checkbox' onChange=checkChecked("+index+",this);>";
}
```